# How do i find out the Number of Lines in a text file?

Tags: c#, streamwriter

```
string s;

Console.WriteLine("Enter What you want to write in your File : ");
s = Convert.ToString(Console.ReadLine());

using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(@"E:/File.txt"))
{
     sw.Write(s);
     sw.Close();
}

using (StreamReader r = new StreamReader(@"E:/File.txt"))
{
     char[] buffer = new char[1024];
     int read;
     int line = 0;
     while ((read = r.ReadBlock(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
     {
          for (int i = 0; i < read; i++)
          {
               if (buffer[i] == '\n' && buffer[i]=='\r')
               {
                    line++;       
               }
          }               
          //Console.WriteLine(buffer[i]);
     }
     Console.WriteLine("Total Lines Are : " + line);
}
```

Im trying to find out the total number of lines so that i may be able to append it more precisely but im quite unable to do so.
It outputs Zero whenever i run it. Sorry for being a Noob. :)

Comment: `int count = File.ReadLines(@"E:\File.txt").Count();`?

Comment: I think the error in your code is that the if should use an OR and not an AND. Like this: `if (buffer[i] == '\n' || buffer[i]=='\r')`

Comment: Some other points to consider in your code is that it counts "\r\n" as +2 lines, but normally it's only +1. Also, I think you are off by one. "a\nb" has two lines, but your code counts 1.

Comment: Is this homework with a requirement to use a "buffer" and/or count lines without using the Framework methods for doing so?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why not direct

```
 using System.IO;
 using System.Linq;

 ... 

 int count = File.ReadLines(@"E:\File.txt").Count();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this:

```
var lines = File.ReadAllLines(@"E:\File.txt");
Console.WriteLine(lines.Length);
```

*Note*: This loads the whole contents of the file into memory, so I think @Dmitry Bychenko's answer is better.

Comment: @elgonzo No problems my friend :)